# How to get an index value based on a string available on that index?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, if-statement, text

For a given text file (sample.txt), I would like to get index value based on a string that is present on that line (index).

An example file contains following text (sample.txt):

> line 1: open a file.

> line 2: Read a file and store it in a variable.

> line 3: check condition using ‘in’ operator for string present in the file or not.

> line 4: If the condition true print the index in which the string is found.

> line 5: Close a file.

if my target string is 'variable'.  The output I would like to have is:
2

Comment: What if the string `"variable"` was present in multiple lines? Would you want the first occurrence line index?

Comment: if a string (e.g. "condition") is present in multiple lines, would expect a result of all the indexes that contain the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```py
def indicesOfQueryOnFile(query, file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        cleanLines = [line for line in f.readlines() if len(line.strip()) > 0]
        indices = [i + 1 for i, line in enumerate(cleanLines) if query in line]
    
    return indices
```

For the text file:

```
line 1: open a file.

line 2: Read a file and store it in a variable.

line 3: check condition using ‘in’ operator for string present in the file or not.

line 4: If the condition true print the index in which the string is found.

line 5: Close a file.

another line with variable
```

It would output:

```py
indicesOfQueryOnFile('variable', 'test.txt')
# [2, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, something like this might be what you are looking for.

```py
def FindLineIndexOfFile(file, text):
    file = open(file, "r")
    line_count = 0
    for lines in file.readlines():
        line_count += 1
        line_index = lines.strip()
        if line_index == text:
            file.close()
            return line_count


index = FindLineIndexOfFile("sample.txt", "hello world")

print(index)
```